# What is the shortcut to rename stuff in Unity on Linux?

Tags: unity, linux

I am using Unity on Ubuntu 16.04 and I can't rename objects or assets using the F2 key as I could when I was using Windows.

What is the shortcut on Linux then?

Comment: You could also just double click?

Comment: @Sidar Double click will take you to the object, you need to click and select, then wait a second or two, then click again to rename. Though using a shortcut is much faster.

Comment: That's what i meant =P but yeah shortcut is faster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a way to just custom make what you need to do. Put the following code inside a script with the same name (doesn't have to be on a game object).

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Reflection;

public class MenuItemsExample
{
    [MenuItem("Edit/Rename _F2")]
    private static void Rename()
    {
        var type = typeof(EditorWindow).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.SceneHierarchyWindow");
        var hierarchyWindow = EditorWindow.GetWindow(type);
        var rename = type.GetMethod("RenameGO", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        rename.Invoke(hierarchyWindow, null);
    }
}
```

This will bind F2 to a rename functionality, using reflection. I've found this from the Unity forums (had to dig a bit but nothing too hard to find). The name part is mine, that's what binds F2 to the function and there's also a nice menu item that appears in your edit menu. Here's a GIF that shows the functionality (shouldn't be dependent on the OS):

[image: Hope this works, since imgur is banned in my country. (Should work in theory)]

Here's [the link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/644608/sending-a-rename-commandevent-to-the-hiearchy-almo.html) to the forum post.